# mysql, how to count results that are the same?

Tags: mysql

i have a database: database with a table: table and some fields:

```
id  fname       dphone      count_pic   dup_id  

6055903 Karla       5126xxx798  1       57  
6173767 Aaliyah     4082xxx534  4       39  
5611411 Aaliyah     4082xxx534  15      39  
5611211 Aaliyah     4082xxx534  18      39  
4234798 Abby        3057xxx974  31      16  
6166691 Walter      6178xxx280  1       74  
3375576 Walter      6178xxx280  17      74
```

what i am trying to do is to select the fields that have the smallest count_pic and the ones that have the bigger count_pic and that have the same dup_id and fname

any ideas how to do this in mysql?

i've got an answer that will match those things but not the fname:

```
 SELECT *
  FROM `table` t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(count_pic) AS minpic,
               MAX(count_pic) AS maxpic,
               dup_id
          FROM `table`
      GROUP BY dup_id) t2 ON t1.dup_id = t2.dup_id
                         AND (t1.count_pic = minpic
                           OR t1.count_pic = maxpic)
```

any ideas how to add the `fname` in the loop? right now it's only keeping track of the same `dup_id`

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (fname, countpic, dupid) in (
   SELECT fname, max(countpic), dupid FROM table GROUP BY fname, dupid
   union
   SELECT fname, min(countpic), dupid FROM table GROUP BY fname, dupid
)
```

Comment: almost there, but i would like to keep the template from my question, this query doesn't seem to get all the results i need